# node_modules\gifsicle: Command failed

Tags: npm-install, yarnpkg, autoreconf, gifsicle

```js
node_modules\gifsicle: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node lib/install.js
Arguments:
Directory: D:\Project\PFS\pfs-portal\node_modules\gifsicle
Output:
‼ connect ETIMEDOUT 49.44.79.236:443
  ‼ gifsicle pre-build test failed
  i compiling from source
  × Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "autoreconf -ivf"
'autoreconf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried this all solution not working for me
Yarn install
clear chache
yarn force install
verbose
deleted node modules nothing is working for me

i want to install packages through yarn